# What actually is needed in proving a function is continuous at a point x0

Tags: uniform-convergence, epsilon-delta

By definition of continuous function, we need the function to satisfied certain properties for all $\epsilon > 0$.
Can I prove the function is continuous by fixing $\epsilon$ to be any $real > 0$?
This problem arise when I try to prove a sequence continuous function $f_n$ uniformly converge to another function $f$.

Given $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$ ,and $f_n$ continuous for any n, show $f$ is continuous at $x_0$:
$d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_0)) <= d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_0)) + d_{Y}(f(x_0),f_n(x_0)) + d_{Y}(f(x),f_n(x))$.
It works well when the fn uniform convergent to f because there exist a function $f_n$ that f is able to "use" for any $\epsilon >0$. (for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N(\epsilon >0)$ s.t. both $d_{Y}(f(x_0),f_n(x_0)) < \epsilon$ and  $d_{Y}(f(x),f_n(x)) 
  <\epsilon$).

But if $f_n$ only pointwise converges to $f$,and because we fix $\epsilon$, we are able to find $N^* := max(N(\epsilon, x_0),N(\epsilon, x))$ such that $d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_0))$ is also bounded within $3\epsilon$ whenever $d(x,x_0) < \delta(f_n)$

Comment: If   the convergence is pointwise but not uniform then $f$ might not be continuous. E.g. on the domain $[0,1],$ if $f_n(x)=x^n. $.

Comment: Uniform convergence does not mean there is an $N$ that works for any $\epsilon > 0$. It means for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ that works for all $x$, For pointwise convergence, instead of having to pick $N^*$ as the max of two values, you have to pick $N^*$ as the max from $\{N(\epsilon, x) \mid x \in U\}$ for some neighborhood $U$ of $x$. That may be an infinite set, and unbounded (see DanielWainfleets counter-example).